# Bulk converting mkv files into mp4 files using only one line of xargs

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, batch-rename

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/420533/1585367) converts a batch of mp4 into mp3 using a for loop.

I want to achieve something similar with only one line of code. After some trial and error, I figured out the following code.

```
ls | grep .mkv | xargs -I {} ffmpeg -i {} -codec copy {}.mp4
```

However, the output filenames are now `video.mkv.mp4`.

I know I can simply write one more line to change the extension

```
ls | grep .mkv.mp4 | sed -e "p;s/\.mkv.mp4$/\.mp4/" | xargs -n2 mv
```

I wonder if there is a one liner solution to it.

Comment: What is the reason you want to remux mkvs to mp4s? mp4 is usually only used with h264 and h265 codecs. If you mkv files have different codecs, you may end up with mp4 files that not all video players can deal with.

Comment: Adobe Premiere Pro does not support mkv files. So I have no choice but to convert them into mp4.

Comment: Wow really? That is baffling.

Comment: FYI: https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro-discussions/premiere-pro-2020-doesn-t-import-mkv/m-p/10937369

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no reason (apart from readability) that you can't put a shell loop in a single line of code - and whether you use a shell loop or `xargs -I{}` you will end up with one invocation of `ffmpeg` for each file.

Regardless, I'd avoid `ls | grep` - instead, use a shell glob. So as a one-liner (in any POSIX-like shell such as bash):

```
for f in ./*.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -codec copy "${f%.mkv}.mp4"; done
```

If you're determined to use `xargs`, then one option would be to switch to the Z-shell where you can use a *glob qualifier* to generate the **r**oot of each matching filename, and then add the input and output extensions as required. So for example:

```
print -rNC1 ./*.mkv(.N:r) | xargs -r0 -I{} ffmpeg -i {}.mkv -codec copy {}.mp4    # NB zsh not bash
```

Note that I switched to null delimiters for the `print` and `xargs` - that allows you to process any legal filename, including filenames containing newline characters.

Another option would be to switch from `xargs` to `GNU parallel`, which has additional options for the replacement string, including `{.}` to substitute the filename without extension (equivalent of the loop version's `${f%.mkv}` or the Z-shell's `:r` modifier):

```
printf '%s\0' ./*.mkv | parallel -q0 ffmpeg -i {} -codec copy '{.}.mp4'    # any shell, including bash
```

Comment: Thank you for the solutions. They are very useful. May I know what is the reason to avoid `ls | grep`?

Comment: @RavenCheuk This answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128987/111521 does pretty good for an explanation as to why you shouldn't use the `ls | grep`.

Comment: ... a slightly more readable exposition at [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). In any case, note that `grep .mkv` would match *any single character* followed by `mkv`, *anywhere in a line* - you'd at least want `grep '\.mkv$'` to match dot extensions specifically.